# How should i license my application?

Tags: c#, application-design, winforms, applications

I developed c# winform application which monitors database and I want to license it.

License will be concurrent based. Standart license 2 concurrent users, Premium users 5 concurrent users.

I want to check license in online. Which means that users need internet connection to use my application.

However this will be database monitoring tool and some companies may not allow internet connection.

I want to hear your thoughts. What do you think about this?

Comment: Voting to close. Your not asking a specific question but asking for an opinion. There is not going to be a correct answer just opinions.  If you re-word your question you may get a better question and better answers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the classical serial number technique could be a solution here.

The technique is similar to what is used by Microsoft to activate a copy of Windows:

- During installation, the user is presented with a serial number prompt.
- If there is an internet connection, the setup application confirms the serial number by querying the licensing server.
- If no internet connection is available, the setup halts, shows a series of numbers and an offline unlock code prompt, and asks the user to call a phone number to get the offline unlock code from the series of numbers.

Depending on the serial number, the setup will be able to install either a standard version or a premium version of the app.

---

Make sure you understand that it will be possible to bypass *any* solution you'll implement. Companies such as Microsoft or Adobe wasted millions of dollars on anti-piracy measures; their products are still installed illegally all over the world.

It's up to you to decide how much money you are ready to spend on licensing. For many products, the best ROI would be achieved by a simple sentence explaining that if the companies are found installing illegal copies of software and/or having more users than allowed, they will be sued, and that, even if you don't have the means to detect the illegal behavior and/or are unable to sue your clients.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If i use serial keys i can not understand how many concurrent users logged in. However if i use online license check with database, i am able to understand how many concurrent users logged in, like adobe use. my question is more like is online license check is a best way to detect it or ethical/technical way is there better solution ?